# How to use JOIN using Hibernate's session.createSQLQuery()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I have two Entity (tables) - Employee & Project. An Employee can have multiple Projects.
Project table's CREATOR_ID field refers to Employee table's ID field. Employee entity does not maintain any reference for Project - but Project entity has a reference for Employee.

Using EntityManager following query works fine -

```
entityManager.createQuery(
    "select e from EmployeeDTO e, ProjectDTO p"
    + " where p.id = ?1 and p.creator.id=e.id");
```

But since I have the LAZY association relationship, I get error:

> Could not initialize proxy - no
>   Session

if I try to access Project info from Employee entity. This is expected and so I am using Hibernate's Session to create query as shown below.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
org.hibernate.Query q = session.createSQLQuery(
    "SELECT E FROM EMPLOYEE_TAB E, PROJECT_TAB P  WHERE P.ID = "
    + projectId + " AND P.CREATOR_ID = E.ID")
    .addEntity("EmployeeDTO ", EmployeeDTO.class)
    .addEntity("ProjectDTO", ProjectDTO.class);
```

But I get error like: "Column 'E' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears 
within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification..."

Can anyone suggest what will be the right JOIN syntax for such case? If I use `("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_TAB E, ........")` - it gives other error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   com.im.server.dto.EmployeeDTO

.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a native SQL query to prefetch `ProjectDTO`s when loading `EmployeeDTO`. Your original query can be rewritten in more elegant way as follows:

```
select e from EmployeeDTO e join e.projects p where p.id = ?1
```

Then you can add a `join fetch` clause in order to prefetch the projects:

```
select distinct e from EmployeeDTO e join e.projects p join fetch e.projects where p.id = ?1
```

**See also:**

- [16.3. Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins)

Comment: I am getting error: "Syntax error: Encountered "where" at line 1, column 52" for both cases. For first case my Query was: "SELECT DISTINCT P FROM ProjectDTO  P   join   P.creator  where P.id = 1".  The "creator" is a member of "ProjectDTO" class of type: "EmployeeDTO".

Comment: My mistake ! I was using "session.createSQLQuery(...)" while I should have used "session.createQuery(...)". Thanks for the right suggestion. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL starts with `SELECT E from EMPLOYEE E ...`, do you mean `SELECT E.*, P.* from EMPLOYEE E ...`?

Comment: No - "SELECT E FROM EMPLOYEE ..." should retrieve all properties of Employee entity/table.